# Nautilus trash doesn't show deleted files on other partitions

Tags: nautilus, trash

Ubuntu 14.04

I have created several symlinks in my home folder to folders in another drive.
I have changed the permissions of that mounted drive:

```
drwxrwxrwx   6 root  root  4,0K oct 13 17:30 media/
```

When I delete some file/folder on some of that symlinks, from Nautilus, it's sent to Trash folder in `media` drive:

```
$ ll /media/.Trash-1000/
total 8,0K
drwx------ 2 simon simon 4,0K oct 13 17:32 files/
drwx------ 2 simon simon 4,0K oct 13 17:32 info/
```

but it isn't showed in Nautilus trash, why?

Comment: I have the same problem (Ubuntu 14.04). Files on partitions /srv and /var don't show up in my trash. I have no idea what is causing this. The files are properly moved to the .Trash-1000 directories on these partitions.

Comment: I have the problem as well (14.04). Would be nice to know if there's anything you can do about this.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, even going so far as to place a shortcut to the trash bin in my file manager so that I could get the space back. In the end the best solution for me was to:

Use the `trash-cli` package which can be installed with `sudo apt-get install trash-cli` and empties all of a users trash with the command `trash-empty`